# Open XML file as read-only with LINQ

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, readonly

I need to open and XML file. The requirement is to be able to open it as read-only, and as read-write as well.

I tried the code below, but so far I can still write to the file.

```
var myFileStream = new FileStream(@"XMLFile.xml",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

var Reader = XmlReader.Create(myFileStream);
var XDoc = XDocument.Load(Reader, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
myFileStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `XDocument` object by following a pattern similar to the `ReadOnlyXElement` pattern detailed in [Is there a way to create an immutable (read-only) XDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585120/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-immutable-read-only-xdocument)

To satisfy the read-write requirement, if you have a `ReadOnlyXDocument` wrapper class, I'd also be tempted to create a `ReadWriteXDocument` wrapper rather than using `XDocument` directly. This way the read-only/read-write distinction is obvious to any consuming code.